Connecting water softener and RO drain into single drain
I have, what I presume, is a 3/4" copper drain line which is currently connected to my heat pump emergency water relief valve. However I'm going to disconnect that and simply point it down into a bucket and have my water softener waste line connect into the wall. I will also have an RO system which requires a waste line into that same connection. Is it "safe" to connect these with a tee or should some other contraption sit in-between the RO and water softener drain connection?
Image below doesn't have the water softener nor the RO system connected yet. It does show the water loop and the drain pipe and current water heater connections.


Where does the drain line go/ Does it just dump outside?

@RMDman  It dumps outside onto pavers in our walkway. Sorry, I forgot to mention that
